# confusion in a combinatorics problem of IMO 2001

Tags: combinatorics

**Original Problem:** Twenty-one girls and twenty-one boys took part in a mathematical competition. It turned out that each contestant solved at most six problems, and for each pair of a girl and a boy, there was at least one problem that was solved by both the girl and the boy. Show that there is a problem that was solved by at least three girls and at least three boys.

**Same problem but a diferet formulation:**
Integers are placed in each of the $441$ cells of a $21 \times 21$ array. Each row and each column has at most 6 different integers in it. Prove that some integer is in at least $3$ rows and at least $3$ columns.

**My Solution:** We have $21$ cells in diagonal and we have to place atmost $6$ integers in it. By pigeon hole principal there is always exist a number from $1$ to $6$ which appears $4$ times in cells of digonal. Hence, we have at least three integers which appears in at least three rows and at least three columns. Rest of cells present in $21 \times 21$, we fill any way.

Surely, I am not able to understand this problem. Please, can any body interpreat this problem?

Comment: Why do you have to place at most six integers into the diagonal?  That is not given.

Comment: Because of we have at most $6$ integers.  Even if we put a subset of integers from $1$ to $6$ then also we are done.

Comment: No, there are many more than $6$ integers.  The integers are the problem numbers.  It is just that each row and column has at most six different integers, but it is not obvious the diagonal has only six.

Comment: This is solved at [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_3) and [Cut the Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/BoysGirlsProblems.shtml)

Comment: I know that it is solved on AOPS website and some other website too.  I am confused by my solution. Clearly, I am not an understanding problem.   Are you telling that we have 36 integers. Or You are telling that at most  $6$ integers can appear in a cell.

Comment: At most $6$ integers can appear in $441$ cells of $21\times 21$ array.

Comment: We are telling you that perhaps it's the case that boy 1 and girl 1 both solved problems 1,2,3,4,5,6 and nothing else, while boy 2 and girl 2 both solved problems 6,7,8,9,10,11, and nothing else. The diagonal then contains at least all numbers from 1 to 11, possibly more depending on the remaining 38 contestants.

Comment: We could have boy n and girl n solve problem n, then everybody solves problem 22.  We would have 22 numbers in the grid and 21 on the diagonal.  @Arthur:  each cell only contains one problem that pair of students solved, so your example does not work.

Comment: We have one number per cell, which is the problem that boy and that girl both solved.  There can be more than 22 problems, but I gave an example that has that many.  There can only be six different numbers in each row and column.  We don't know how many different problems there are, though one could work out the maximum.  The published solutions do not depend on it.

Comment: @RossMillikan The can be more than one number per cell: "for each pair of a girl and a boy, there was **at least** one problem that was solved by both the girl and the boy." (Emphasis mine.) My example has at most six numbers per cell, yours has two (each cell on your diagonal contains 22, along with the corresponding $n$).

Comment: @Arthur We may as well assume there is only one number per cell: if there are more, deleting all but one of them gives us a grid that also satisfies the constraints, and this can only make it harder to find a number appearing in three rows and columns.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I haven't read any of the solutions, but are you certain that this always works, no matter which of the multiple numbers we delete? Also, even if it does work, I think Ross Millikan is a bit harsh when he says that my example doesn't work for the reason that I have multiple numbers in a cell, when that, in my opinion, is a more correct translation of the original problem.